# How to implement RTSP Push for my source stream to push to Wowza Cloud?

Tags: rtsp, rtp, wowza

I have written software that captures RTP packets from my an external camera and is able to forward them on. I created a SDP file and loaded it into VLC and then streamed the RTP packets to VLC and confirmed it plays correctly.

Now I would like to stream to Wowza Cloud. It seems like the way to do that is with an RTSP Push stream which I have configured. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation regarding what the protocol is for RTSP Push.

I understand RTSP (Pull) and how to implement that, but not RTSP Push. It seems like cameras support this, so this must be an established protocol, but push is not mentioned anywhere in the RTSP spec. Wowza Cloud gives me an endpoint, port, stream name, and authentication, but I don't know what to do with them. It seems like SDP Announce is involved, but there is no clear guide on how to implement it.

Can anyone explain how to implement this RTSP Push protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTSP Push protocol to stream to Wowza consists of the following RTSP commands:

1. OPTIONS
2. ANNOUNCE
3. SETUP (for each RTP stream, i.e. Audio and Video)
4. RECORD
5. TEARDOWN (after the streaming is complete)

The ANNOUNCE is the same as DESCRIBE, only you are pushing the SDP information as the body of the command.

During the SETUP, the server will respond with the IP and Port to send the RTP packets over UDP (via the Transport header).

The details of the process can be inspected by using FFMPEG and Wireshark.  The ffmpeg command is the following:

```
ffmpeg -re -i inputfile.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -vcodec libx264 -r 23.976 -threads 0 -b:v: 1024k -bufsize 1024k -preset veryfast -profile:v baseline -tune film -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -acodec aac -b:a 192k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.2:1935/live/myStream
```

Finally, it is critical to keep the Socket open during the entire session, or the streaming session will be closed.